# React: Render performance with both onBlur and onFocus

Tags: reactjs

- live - https://tuchk4.github.io/onBlurExample
- sources - https://github.com/tuchk4/onBlurExample

> In this example - "render" is a time between parent component constructor and componentDidMount.
>   (Parent component - I mean buttons list wrapper)

Open console at devtools. Steps:

Render 1000 buttons with onFocus:

- Reload
- Click "FOCUS"

render ~0.02 (OK)

---

Render 1000 buttons with onBlur:

- Reload
- Click "BLUR"

render  ~0.02 (OK)

---

Render 1000 buttons with both onFocus and onBlur:

- Reload
- Click "BOTH"

**render ~0.3** (Strange)

---

Re-Render 1000 buttons with both onFocus and onBlur:

- Reload
- Click "BOTH"
- **(~0.3 sec)** (Strange)
- Click "Clear"
- Click "BOTH"
- (~0.015 sec) (OK)

---

Question:

Why initial render time for component with both onBlur and onFocus is much bigger than others?

Comment: I'm guessing because it has to set up twice the amount of event listeners?

Comment: @FabianSchultz btw. If you add `onClick` - render time will not be changed. But if merge other events (onMouseMove, onKeyUp etc) - if there are more than one such event - render time increase in ~10 times. I will update question.